# SQL Server - defining prescence

Tags: sql-server

I have thousands of daily report spreadsheets from a number of locations that include a list of each staff member working that day. Unfortunately the reports are not easy to sort into chronological order from the filename or the creation date. I will be using .Net to populate SQL Server tables with the data.

My aim is to be able to produce a report that looking like this, showing the 2 weeks (might be more or less) that each person worked:

```
'Worker 1' 'Location A'  2016-04-05 to 2016-04-19
'Worker 2' 'Location A'  2016-04-19 to 2016-05-03
'Worker 2' 'Location B'  2017-01-01 to 2017-01-14
'Worker 2' 'Location A'  2017-02-01 to 2017-02-14
```

Unfortunately, as each report is processed, all I know is the location and a list of people that were there on the day. So, I don't know until later whether a person has finished their 2 weeks or not.

My question is - what is the best structure to store the data to allow analysis?

I thought of 1 record per location and worker, with start date & end data, but this won't work if Worker 1 works at Location A for 2 weeks, has 2 weeks off and comes back to the same location, as I would want to present that in my report as 2 sessions of work.

I also considered 1 record per day per location with 1 field per worker but this would get messy as workers came on & off hire.

I also considered 1 record per worker per location with 1 field per day but I already have 3 years worth of reports so the amount of fields will get unwieldy.

Is there a good way to record the initial data to be able to extract as I want it for analysis? Or should I just pre-process the daily reports to ensure they are processed in chronological order before writing them into tables?

Comment: Have you considered 1 record per worker per day for initial import?

Comment: I hadn't, but it is a good idea so I have used that idea now. Looks like it will be a multi-stage process to get the output that I need.